# MySQL SELECT Query with WHERE clause Not returning rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables InvoicePDF and UserMaster.  They are connected using a common column (CompanyID).  When I try to run the below query, I am getting empty result set.  Curious to know why?

By the way I wish to return all the rows of the first table matching the CompanyID in the second table where the CustomerID is 3.

```
SELECT A.CompanyID,
B.COMPANYID,
B.CUSTOMERID,
A.InvPDFFileName,
A.InvMonth,
A.InvYear,
A.InvoiceID 
FROM InvoicePDF A, UserMaster B 
WHERE B.CompanyID=A.CompanyID and B.CustomerID=3
```

Comment: try this `select A.CompanyID
 , B.COMPANYID
 , B.CUSTOMERID
 , A.InvPDFFileName
 , A.InvMonth
 , A.InvYear
 , A.InvoiceID 
from InvoicePDF A 
left join UserMaster B on B.CompanyID=A.CompanyID 
where B.CustomerID=3`

Comment: Without seeing your data, the only thing we can say is that there are no invoices for customerID 3. What does `select * from usermaster where customerid = 3` returns?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, and you will get better answers: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

use left join and apply your condition `B.CustomerID=3` in ON Cluase - and always use an explicit join instead of implicit one

```
SELECT A.CompanyID,B.COMPANYID,
B.CUSTOMERID,A.InvPDFFileName,
A.InvMonth,A.InvYear,A.InvoiceID 
FROM InvoicePDF A left join UserMaster B on B.CompanyID=A.CompanyID and B.CustomerID=3
```

Comment: After executing your query, I am unable to see the result and no rows are selected

Comment: @Bala, could you please add your sample data in your question

Answer (score 0):

Your query works as expected

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INVOICEPDF,USERMASTER;
CREATE TABLE INVOICEPDF(COMPANYID INT   , InvPDFFileName varchar(3),InvoiceID int);
create table usermaster(COMPANYID int,CUSTOMERID int);

insert into invoicepdf values
(1,'aaa',1),(2,'bbb',2),(1,'aaa',3);
insert into usermaster values
(1,3),(2,4),(3,3);



SELECT A.CompanyID,
B.COMPANYID,
B.CUSTOMERID,
A.InvPDFFileName,
#A.InvMonth,
#A.InvYear,
A.InvoiceID 
FROM InvoicePDF A, UserMaster B 
WHERE B.CompanyID=A.CompanyID and B.CustomerID=3;

+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+
| CompanyID | COMPANYID | CUSTOMERID | InvPDFFileName | InvoiceID |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+
|         1 |         1 |          3 | aaa            |         1 |
|         1 |         1 |          3 | aaa            |         3 |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which means one or more of your where conditions is false.